# which programing language i can use to develop both android and ios applications as frontend and django as backend?

Tags: android, ios, django

which programing language i can to develop both android and ios applications as front-end and Django as back-end ?

T am developing a back-end using Django. Which is the best language for both android and ios for application and ease of linking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently developed 2 mobile apps. I've used Django for backend and [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial) with [Expo tool](https://expo.io/) for front-end.

If you use react native then you can develop both the Android and iOS app in one go with minor config changes.

React Native is a JavaScript framework for building native mobile apps. It uses the React framework and offers large amount of inbuilt components and APIs.

Lastly for ease of linking I used [Graphene-Python](https://graphene-python.org/) which is a library for building [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) APIs in Python.

There is learning curve involved with this stack, but once you know how to use it properly then it makes your life very easy.

Comment: Cheers. Also if you think the answer solves your problem, please accept this is your answer.